# How will the site be affected by the new changes? (left nav)

Tags: discussion, design

In the recent meta post [Left nav, responsive design, and theming next steps](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/309349/left-nav-responsive-design-and-theming-next-steps), visual changes to many (all?) Stack Exchange sites were announced.

Do we have any idea at the moment how these changes will affect our site?

Comment: They will reach out to us once they have more concrete ideas about the specific design plans. As to the general list of things that will and won't stay customizable, that's detailed in the meta question you linked to. All in all, I don't think too much will change here, we don't have as flamboyant a design as some of the other sites.